# Django throws existOperationalError for DB

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psql, saleor

Running Django throws `conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) does not existOperationalError: FATAL:  database "saleor"`

I have used:

```sql
CREATE USER saleor WITH PASSWORD 'somepassword';
CREATE DATABASE saleor WITH OWNER saleor ENCODING 'utf-8';
```

When I enter `psql -U saleor` in a terminal it works and logs in to db saleor with user saleor.

My connection string is: `postgres://saleor:somepassword@localhost/saleor`

When I run `python3 manage.py migrate` it throws an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Rick/projects/jorcustom/e-commerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Rick/projects/jorcustom/e-commerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Rick/projects/jorcustom/e-commerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

[..removed 14 lines..]

    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Rick/projects/jorcustom/e-commerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Rick/projects/jorcustom/e-commerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
" does not existOperationalError: FATAL:  database "saleor
```

Comment: Show us the `DATABASES` section of `settings.py`.

Comment: `DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'),
        conn_max_age=600)}`

Comment: .env `export DATABASE_URL='postgres://saleor:somepassword@localhost/saleor'
export DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='noreply@example.com'
export OPENEXCHANGERATES_API_KEY=''
export CACHE_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
export CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/1
export SECRET_KEY='changem'
export JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION=True
export VATLAYER_ACCESS_KEY=''`

Comment: This is likely a database connection error. You need to make sure that the DB connection settings are correct & the DB is up & accessible with the said credentials. One way to do that is by checking the settings from within `python manage.py shell` and see what output you get for `settings.DATABASES`.